# VMWare ESXi 6 with pfsense as router on one nic for 3x windows server

Tags: vmware-esxi, pfsense

I just ordered dedicated server i7 4790 with 16GB ram and 1xHDD 7200rpp, with one Nic (2 available, 1 is unplugged), 5 Ips.

Is it possible to run 3x VMs (Windows server) and 1x VMs for pfsense on current hardware?

If it's possible, I would like to know how to config pfSense and Esxi. Because I want to setup private network between VMs, each VMs (Windows server) has 1 private IP and public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Create the virtual switches in ESX, and assign the NICs on the VMs accordingly. You'll have one vswitch for the public network, and at least one additional with no physical NIC associated with it for the private network.

You probably don't want both a public and private IP on the Windows VMs, as that would defeat the purpose of having a firewall. Unless you can't NAT for some reason. The Windows servers probably should be private-only, and only connected to the private vswitch.